# Expression in ng-controller for a JSON-Objects with AngularJS and Ionic

Tags: json, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-controller

I parse JSON objects to create html elements. In my case, I create from json file Buttons:

```
{
    "type": "button",
    "id": "comButton",
    "icon": "ion-chatboxes",
    "name": "Communication",
    "onclick": "",
    "controller": "somemthctrl",
    "ngclick": "launchSomemethod()",
    "color": "white",
    "backgroundcolor": "#ff5db1",
    "font-size": "20px"
}
```

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('generateButtonCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('JSON/buttons.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.components = data;
    });
});
```

From the HTML page, I call the components from the json file:

```
<a ng-repeat="component in components"
   style="color:{{component.color}}; background-color:{{component.backgroundcolor}} "
   id="{{component.id}}"
   class="{{component.type}}"
   href="{{component.onclick}}"
   ng-click="{{component.ngclick}}"
   ng-controller="{{component.controller}}">

    <i class="{{component.icon}}"><br></i>
    {{component.name}}
</a>
```

In the case `ng-click="{{component.ngclick}}"` und `ng-controller="{{component.controller}}"` will not be included.

At the appropriate places I get from my editor WebStorm following error: **Identifier or String literal or numeric literal expected.**

I have a `{{expression}}` Problem. How can I integrate the `ng-controller` and `ng-click` as a string from a json object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite tricky. Angular team on their doc suggests that controller should be registered to a module while the DOM is being parsed.

> All the $scope properties will be available to the template at the point in the DOM where the Controller is registered.

Link: [Angular controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

---

- Use *$controllerProvider* to register the controller This [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs)
  shed's some light on how controllers are resolved at later point of
  the time, which might help you in designing your code as desired.
- *ng-click* you can give an expression or a method which is inside the controller of *$scope* tree. Both the expression and/or function
  search happens inside the *$scope* tree at the compile time of your
  template.

---

### Update As per the fiddler requested

---

I have corrected the fiddler code, removed unwanted lines, errors and made it working.

Now your template is dynamic binding to the JavaScript code at the run-time.

[Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/zox8yh55/4/) Link

**Javascript**:

```
 var myApp = angular.module('starter', []);
myApp.config(['$sceDelegateProvider', function($sceDelegateProvider) {
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        'self',
        'https://api.myjson.com/**'
    ]);
}]);

myApp.controller('generateHTMLCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $compile, $interpolate, $templateCache) {
    $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1gkh0').success(function (data) {      
        for(var i in data){
            var interpolated = $interpolate($templateCache.get("tpl").trim())(data[i]);            
            angular.element(document.querySelector("#loadhere")).append($compile(interpolated)($scope));            
        }               
    });
});

myApp.controller("OpenLinkCtrl", function ($scope) {    
        $scope.OpenLink = function () {
           alert("Link open");
        }    
});
```

**Html**:

```
 <body ng-app="starter" class="padding" style="text-align: center">
 <div class="row responsive-md" ng-controller="generateHTMLCtrl" id="loadhere"></div>                                        
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="tpl">
                 <div class="col">
                    <a style="color:{{color}}; background-color:{{backgroundcolor}} "
                       id="{{id}}" class="{{type}}" href="{{topage}}" ng-controller="{{controller}}" ng-click="{{function}}"><i class="{{icon}}"><br></i>{{name}}</a>
                </div>
          </script>
    </body>
```

---

**Explanation:**

- Used interpolate service
- Used compiler service

**Note:** Interpolator cannot parse on array of objects. Hence used for loop to interpolate each oject array and append it to the DOM.

More info on compiler and interpolation can be found [here](http://excellencenodejsblog.com/angularjs-compile-parse-interpolate/)

Comment: I get the error message:

**Error: ng:areq Bad Argument**

`Argument '{{component.controller}}' is not a function, got undefined`

Comment: create a fiddle to look into the issue.

Comment: Hier [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fn9eehux/): I hope that can help to clear the situation

Comment: @Ramosta updated. Your fiddle contained lots of error and unwanted codes. I have cleaned it for you. Adapt it for your ionic code.

Comment: thank you so much for all your help. It works well. But my JSON object must always contain the pairs `controller ` and `function`. So `controller` and `function` must not be empty. Otherwise it doesn't work. But there are cases where these pairs may be empty. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: I am glad that the above code helped you. And yes to compile the template Angular expects its template dependencies to be present in the scope and templates directives. I would suggest you to run through the data received in success callback and attach a dummy expressions to the object so that compile will not be broken.

Comment: Many thanks. That was the solution. One last thing:I think my responsive grid doesn't work properly because of `<script type="text/ng-template" id="tpl"></script>` tag. The Grid is not more responsive. So it isn't automatically adjusted on different screen size and set no linebreak for many Buttons or components. Either they merge into each other or all the buttons are in a column below the each other. How can i solve this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87248/discussion-between-nirus-and-ramosta).

Comment: since yesterday I try to optimize the responsive Grid system for my buttons from the JSON file. I succeeded so far not. I've created a new [**question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32089855/ionic-responsive-grid-doesnt-work). Perhaps you would read the question and help me with my problem?

Comment: The parsing from JSON works on the Android wonderful. on the Google browser Chrome also. But on IOS and Firefox makes problems and the parsed component are not displayed on IOS and Firefox Browser. I don't know whether the following error is the because:

`Uncaught TypeError: Can not Read Property '1' of zero`

Otherwise I do not get a another error message. Can you say what it could be?

Comment: I get on Firefox the following error:
`Error: document.querySelector(...).innerText is undefined`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it's possible the ng-controller could be a `{{ expression }}`.
The workarround it's creating a function that returns the name of the controller that you want and you can assign to a var inside the controller...

In other case, why you want to use a different controller for each button?

Comment: I have many cases where I need a different controller for some buttons.