# Ionic responsive grid doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, responsive-design, ionic-framework

I created a responsive grid in Ionic which doesn't work properly. The Grid is not responsive. So it isn't automatically adjusted on different screen size and set no linebreak if I add many Buttons or delete these to the/from the system. Either they merge into each other or all the buttons are in a column below the each other on small screens. How can i solve this?

I add or delete all the buttons in a JSON-File. From there I parse the Buttons in to the system.

**JSON:** 7 Buttons

```
[
  {
    "_comment": "Games",
    "type": "button",
    "id": "entertainmentButton",
    "icon": "ion-film-marker",
    "name": "Game and entertainment",
    "topage": "servicePage.html",
    "color": "white",
    "function": "OpenLink()",
    "controller": "OpenLinkCtrl",
    "backgroundcolor": "#0066FF",
    "font-size": "26px"
  },
  {
    "_comment": "Logo",
    "type": "button",
    "id": "MainPageLogo",
    "icon": "",
    "image": "../img/icon/logo_moenchsweiler.png",
    "name": "second link",
    "topage": "",
    "function": "OpenLink()",
    "controller": "OpenLinkCtrl",
    "color": "",
    "backgroundcolor": "",
    "font-size": ""
  },
  {
    "_comment": "Logo",
    "type": "button",
    "id": "MainPageLogo",
    "icon": "",
    "image": "../img/icon/logo_moenchsweiler.png",
    "name": "second link",
    "topage": "",
    "function": "OpenLink()",
    "controller": "OpenLinkCtrl",
    "color": "",
    "backgroundcolor": "",
    "font-size": ""
  },
  {
    "_comment": "Logo",
    "type": "button",
    "id": "MainPageLogo",
    "icon": "",
    "image": "../img/icon/logo_moenchsweiler.png",
    "name": "second link",
    "topage": "",
    "function": "OpenLink()",
    "controller": "OpenLinkCtrl",
    "color": "",
    "backgroundcolor": "",
    "font-size": ""
  },
  {
    "_comment": "Logo",
    "type": "button",
    "id": "MainPageLogo",
    "icon": "",
    "image": "../img/icon/logo_moenchsweiler.png",
    "name": "second link",
    "topage": "",
    "function": "OpenLink()",
    "controller": "OpenLinkCtrl",
    "color": "",
    "backgroundcolor": "",
    "font-size": ""
  },
  {
    "_comment": "Logo",
    "type": "button",
    "id": "MainPageLogo",
    "icon": "",
    "image": "../img/icon/logo_moenchsweiler.png",
    "name": "second link",
    "topage": "",
    "function": "OpenLink()",
    "controller": "OpenLinkCtrl",
    "color": "",
    "backgroundcolor": "",
    "font-size": ""
  },
  {
    "_comment": "Logo",
    "type": "button",
    "id": "MainPageLogo",
    "icon": "",
    "image": "../img/icon/logo_moenchsweiler.png",
    "name": "second link",
    "topage": "",
    "function": "OpenLink()",
    "controller": "OpenLinkCtrl",
    "color": "",
    "backgroundcolor": "",
    "font-size": ""
  }
]
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('starter', []);
myApp.config(['$sceDelegateProvider', function($sceDelegateProvider) {
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        'self',
        ''
    ]);
}]);

myApp.controller('generateHTMLCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $compile, $interpolate, $templateCache) {    
    $http.get('myjsonfile.json').success(function (data) {      
        for(var i in data){            
            var interpolated = $interpolate($templateCache.get("tpl").trim())(data[i]);            
            angular.element(document.querySelector("#loadhere")).append($compile(interpolated)($scope));            
        }               
    });
});

myApp.controller("OpenLinkCtrl", function ($scope) {    
        $scope.OpenLink = function () {
           alert("Link open");
        }    
});
```

**HTML:**

```
    <body ng-app="starter" class="padding" style="text-align: center">
   <div class="row responsive-md" ng-controller="generateHTMLCtrl" id="loadhere"></div>
   <script type="text/ng-template" id="tpl">
      <div class="col">
         <a style="color:{{color}}; background-color:{{backgroundcolor}} " id="{{id}}" class="{{type}}" href="{{topage}}" ng-controller="{{controller}}" ng-click="{{function}}"> <i class="{{icon}}"><br></i>{{name}}</a>
      </div>
   </script>
</body>
```

**What do I need to modify in HTMl-code that the Grid is responsive?**

**Edit:**

It should look like here, e.g:

```
<div class="row responsive-sm">
            <div class="col">
                <button style="width: 100px; height: 100px">Test</button>
                <button style="width: 100px; height: 100px">Test</button>
                <button style="width: 100px; height: 100px">Test</button>
                <button style="width: 100px; height: 100px">Test</button>
                <button style="width: 100px; height: 100px">Test</button>
                <button style="width: 100px; height: 100px">Test</button>
                <button style="width: 100px; height: 100px">Test</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This code displays the buttons as follows:

on large screen size:

[image]

bit smaller:

[image]

very small:

[image]

**Edited:**

**The solution:**

```
<div ng-controller="generateHTMLCtrl" id="loadhere">
            <script type="text/ng-template" id="tpl">
                <a style="color:{{color}}; background-color:{{backgroundcolor}};"
                   id="{{id}}" class="{{type}}" href="{{topage}}"
                   ng-controller="{{controller}}" ng-click="{{function}}">
                    <i class="{{icon}}"><br></i>{{name}}
                </a>
            </script>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you want is something more like this:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="image in images" ng-if="$index % 4 === 0">
        <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index < images.length">
            <img ng-src="{{images[$index].src}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
        <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index + 1 < images.length">
            <img ng-src="{{images[$index + 1].src}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
        <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index + 2 < images.length">
            <img ng-src="{{images[$index + 2].src}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
        <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index + 3 < images.length">
            <img ng-src="{{images[$index + 3].src}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

This will create a maximum of 4 images per row that wrap and stack. You can also make it more or less images per by changing ng-if statement in for rows and then the amount of images in that row

When you are on every forth image, you are going to show the row class, thus creating a new row
you will pre-allocate four columns for you row, but you would first check to see if it will ever be filled to prevent an undefined exception
If the image exists at the specified index, then add it to the column

Edit!
Try this
add this css class:

```
.gallery {
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

then put this in your html:

```
<ion-content ng-controller="ExampleController" ng-init="loadImages()" class="gallery">
  <span ng-repeat="image in images">
    <img src="{{image}}" width="150px">
  </span>
```

since ionic is built on built on top of flex box you can make a flexbox grid in ionic.

Comment: Can you give me a concrete example on my example? you can correct my code perhaps?

(My HTML-example can be seen above)

Comment: It may just be easier to follow along with this example: https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/03/make-a-gallery-like-image-grid-using-ionic-framework/

Comment: I know the example already. I unfortunately didn't continue with it.

Comment: see my edit, that is a alternative to the other method.

Comment: Thanks for the orientation. The solution is the use of the `div` without `row responsive-sm` and `col` classes. rather than `row responsive-sm` and `col` you can also use your suggestion `.gallery`. I have revised my question and added the solution.